# Import video files from "Videos" application into my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is there a way to import (access) video files from **Videos** application in iOS? I have synchronized some video files through iTunes, now I would like to import them into my app. I've searched on google, but I didn't find nothing really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to modify the videos, I think you should access them instead of importing them.

In any case start by get assets groups with `[ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:]`, set their `assetsFilter` to `allVideos` and `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:` to get video `ALAsset` objects.

Then follow the class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

Also take a look at this library and AssetsLibrary class [wrappers](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/tree/master/Source/Assets).

There are some methods to ease [asset groups](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/master/Source/Assets/NBUAssetsLibrary.h#L113) and [assets](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUImagePicker/blob/master/Source/Assets/NBUAssetsGroup.h#L87) retrieval. Feel free to extend video support as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

The [AVPlayerDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101) sample project demonstrates accessing videos in the camera roll, media library, and those shared through iTunes syncing.